# How to get Identity insert to work with my model

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I am trying to allow users to create objects "Rooms". They will be able to add items to the room, and delete and create rooms for their account.

I have my table set up like this,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rooms](

[Value] [money] NULL,

[Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

[RoomID] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

[User] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL)
```

And my insert code like this,

```
[HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Name, User, 
 RoomID")] Room room)

    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)

        {

            using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())

            {

           db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Rooms ON");

               room.User = User.Identity.GetUserId();  

               db.Rooms.Add(room);

               await db.SaveChangesAsync();

           db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Rooms OFF");

                transaction.Commit();

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        return View(room);
    }
```

Whenever I try adding an object room to my database, I leave the RoomID undefined. I expect the database to automatically increment the ID, but it is throwing an error....

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Rooms__328639191EFADF47'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Rooms'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.

It is setting the value of RoomID to 0 everytime.

Comment: It think you got it the wrong way round. When you set identity insert to On this means that **you** have to supply the primary key value. When it's off, the database does it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 .

Comment: _"SET IDENTITY_INSERT Rooms ON"_ you shouldn't be doing this

Comment: @ADyson When I turn it off I get this, Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Rooms' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: @Liet maybe you need to **not** include "RoomID" in your `[Bind(Include` if the dB is going to create it. you might want to look into View Models

Comment: @zgood I took it out of my Bind, and its still throwing the same error. My view Model for RoomID looks like this,         public int RoomID { get; set; }

Comment: Try explicitly adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` above RoomID in your model. Should not really need it since you are following convention, but give it a try.

Comment: @SteveGreene actually he is not following convention... if he was his id field would be `Id` not `RoomID`... he is inserting into the `Room` table

Comment: @zgood "Code First infers that a property is a primary key if a property on a class is named “ID” (not case sensitive), or the class name followed by "ID" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in

Comment: Still new to coding so any help is appreciated, I did try adding [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)], threw the same error. Im also using database first, which is how my models were generated